# Nav Tab active moment image not change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im added tab for the image icon , im try to do that when i click the button (active button) after image icon change to be `book_hover.png` font color is change but image icon not change ,how to replace the image after NavTab active moment

```css
.footer-tab .tooter-nav-tab {
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0rem;
  background: white;
  border-top: 1px solid #c9cfd9;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

p.tab-txt {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.footer-tab ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #c9cfd9;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.footer-tab li {
  float: left;
}

.footer-tab .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  color: white;

  background-color: #8bb6f3;
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #fff;
}

.footer-tab li a {
  display: block;
  color: #3f5370;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-tab li a:hover {
  background-color: #8bb6f3;
  color: white;
}

.footer-tab-img :active {
  background:url'https://image.ibb.co/ffSy9F/book_hover.png')no-repeat;
  color: white;
}
/*footernavtab*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="footer-tab">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="img-01 w-25"><a href="" class="nav-link"}}

    <span class="footer-tab-img active">
     <a href="#"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/mOHJbv/book.png" alt="book" border="0"></a>
     </span>
        <p class="tab-txt">Book</p>
   </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you have nested anchor tags? - this is invalid HTML

Comment: @ovokuro Sir im try to using `anchor tag inside another anchor tag` not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fixed my issue, im used this class `footer-tab-img-01` and added separate color image and code crete like this

```
`span.footer-tab-img-01 { background: url('/Image/users.png') no-repeat; width: 32px; height: 32px; display: block; margin-left:1.2rem; }

.nav-link.active span.footer-tab-img-01 { background: url('/Image/users-hover.png') no-repeat; width: 32px; height: 32px; display: block; margin-left:1.2rem; }`
```

---

```
<div class="footer-tab">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="img-01 w-25"><a href="" class="nav-link"}}

                <span class="footer-tab-img-01">

                    </span>
        <p class="tab-txt">Book</p>
   </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```